# Plotting a histogram with numeric and str data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have some data that looks like this:

```
df1 = df[['Borough','Initial_Cost']]
counts = print(df1['Borough'].value_counts(dropna=False))
print(counts)


MANHATTAN        6310
BROOKLYN         2866
QUEENS           2121
BRONX             974
STATEN ISLAND     575
Name: Borough, dtype: int64
```

The concept seems pretty straightforward, but I keep getting an empty histogram (the data seems fine but the plot is completely blank).  I am trying to make a histogram that looks something like this.

[image]

The data set was fetched from here.

https://github.com/johnashu/datacamp/blob/master/dob_job_application_filings_subset.csv

Comment: Take a look at the [bar plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) in `matplotlib`.

Comment: Did you really mean to set `count` equal to the return of a print function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is this:

```
df['Borough'].value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

Example with few datas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Borough':['MANHATTAN','BROOKLYN','BROOKLYN','QUEENS','QUEENS','BROOKLYN','MANHATTAN','MANHATTAN','MANHATTAN']})
df['Borough'].value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joe.  That was just what I needed.  Is there is good webiste that explains how these things work?  Something simple to intermediate level?  I Googled for an answer for a while before posting my question, and I tried several ideas, but I just couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: @ryguy72 you are welcome. Please consider to accept and upvote the answer :) Most of my knowledge is by experience, but this link maybe could help you  https://community.modeanalytics.com/python/tutorial/counting-and-plotting-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `plt.bar` to plot your data:

```
data = {'MANHATTAN'    :     6310,
        'BROOKLYN'     :     2866,
        'QUEENS'       :     2121,
        'BRONX'        :     974,
        'STATEN ISLAND':     575}
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
plt.bar(names, values)
plt.show()
```

[image]